What role does homotopy play in Karoubi's K-Theory?
In Karoubi's book K-Theory An Introduction, he defines the groups $K^{p,q}(\mathcal{C})$ for a pseudo-abelian Banach category as equivalence classes of triples $(E,F,\alpha)$, where $E,F \in \mathcal{C}^{p,q+1}$ (with $C^{p,q}$ being a Clifford algebra) and $\alpha\colon \varphi(E) \to \varphi(F)$ is an isomorphism ($\varphi\colon \mathcal{C}^{p,q+1} \to \mathcal{C}^{p,q}$).
He defines the equivalence relation to be as follows: An object $(E,F,\alpha)$ is elementary if $E = F$ and $\alpha$ is homotopic to the identity.
Two objects are then equivalent if they are isomorphic up to an elementary object.
I have two questions:

Why the notion of homotopy?
Taking $\mathcal{C}$ to be vector bundles over a (smooth) manifold $X$, how does one see that $K^{0,0}(X) \cong K(X)$ (where $K(X)$ is defined via exact sequences)?

